# Mosquitto buffering not working

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I have the following mosquitto.conf but when internet goes out, it does not buffer and send to AWS IoT when internet comes back.

Questions:

1. What have I done wrong with the mosquitto config that the offline buffering is not working as expected?
2. I am thinking of writing my own bridge on NodeJS. Any recommendation of NodeJS MQTT library that supports offline buffering?

Thank you!

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

# =================================================================
# Bridges to AWS IOT
# =================================================================

# AWS IoT endpoint, use AWS CLI 'aws iot describe-endpoint'
connection awsiot
address aws.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:8883

# Specifying which topics are bridged
topic outTopic out 1

# Setting protocol version explicitly
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_insecure false

# Bridge connection name and MQTT client Id,
# enabling the connection automatically when the broker starts.
cleansession true
clientid bridgeawsiot
start_type automatic
notifications false
log_type all

cafile /home/pi/ca.crt
keyfile /home/pi/server.key
certfile /home/pi/server.crt
tls_version tlsv1

# =================================================================
# Certificate based SSL/TLS support
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
#Path to the rootCA
bridge_cafile /home/pi/rootCA.cer

# Path to the PEM encoded client certificate
bridge_certfile /home/pi/bridge.cert.pem

# Path to the PEM encoded client private key
bridge_keyfile /home/pi/bridge.private.key
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cleansession true` in your bridge config will mean that no messages are queued when the bridge is down.

Comment: I realized the reason I was doing `cleansession=true` due to restriction that AWS IoT supports only cleansession=true. Any alternatives of keeping local cache?

Comment: Just because the broker at the other end (AWT) doesn't support queuing messages doesn't mean you have to enforce it on your end. If you remove the flag from the config, it should queue them on the pi to send to the AWS